# Select MySQL data with where clause in 2 tables

Tags: sql, mysql, join, one-to-many

I have 2 MySQL tables like in the example below:

CARS

```
Id     CAR NAME          AGE

1   Ford        2 years
2   AUDI        1 years 
3   Ford        2 years
```

OPTIONS

```
Id  id_car   option

1    1      ESP
2    2          ABS
3    3          ABS
4    3          ESP
```

And I need to **select all cars of 2 years old which have ABS AND ESP**.
So it should return in this example:  3   Ford

Answer (score 8):

The group by/having will ensure that the car has both of the desired features.

```
select c.id, c.name
    from cars c
        inner join options o
            on c.id = o.id_car
                and o.option in ('ABS','ESP')
    where c.age = 2
    group by c.id, c.name
    having count(distinct o.option) = 2
```

Comment: @Haim Evgi: That's the reason for the group by/having. That structure ensures that the car has *both* features, not simply either/or.

Comment: OO I like that thats very advanced, Thx you just showed me some thing new

Comment: +1 for the having solution and because you were faster then me. Sorry it's not possible to give another +1 for the indentation, a style I will adopt starting right now :)

Comment: pls i've a doubt in this case at the time of joining won't it take all result having abs ,esp?

Comment: @harish: The join alone will find cars that may have only one of the desired features. It is the group by/having portion of the query that will ensure that only cars with both features are returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id_car FROM OPTIONS WHERE GROUP_CONCAT(option) ='ABS,ESP' 
GROUP BY id_car) 
WHERE age ='2 years' GROUP BY CARS.name
```

Comment: subselect solution is much slower then the Joe's group by/having solution

Comment: sorry i was typing the answer while he posted

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join on the OPTIONS table:

```
SELECT c.* FROM CARS c
JOIN OPTIONS o ON o.id_car=c.id AND o.option='ABS'
JOIN OPTIONS o2 ON o2.id_car=c.id AND o2.option='ESP'
WHERE c.age >= 2
```

Or subqueries:

```
SELECT c.* FROM CARS c
WHERE c.age >= 2
AND c.id IN ( SELECT o.id_car FROM OPTIONS o WHERE o.id_car=c.id AND o.option='ABS')
AND c.id IN ( SELECT o.id_car FROM OPTIONS o WHERE o.id_car=c.id AND o.option='ESP')
```

Comment: He first needs to change the AGE field to INT for your query to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CARS LEFT JOIN `OPTIONS` ON `OPTIONS`.`id_car` = `CARS`.`id` WHERE `OPTIONS`.`option` LIKE '%ABS%'
```

Will do ABS if you wanting more you will have to have PHP write the SQL additions per Options so your End result would be

```
SELECT * FROM CARS LEFT JOIN `OPTIONS` ON `OPTIONS`.`id_car` = `CARS`.`id` WHERE (`OPTIONS`.`option` LIKE '%ABS%' OR  `OPTIONS`.`option` LIKE '%ESP%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the 'age' column, either to 'date_created', or just leave it as age and only use an integer.

If you use as an integer, just do this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.car
   FROM cars c
   INNER JOIN options o
   ON o.id_car = c.id
   WHERE c.age >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks very much to everyone...i just tried                     SELECT c.* FROM CARS c
JOIN OPTIONS o ON o.id_car=c.id AND o.option='ABS'
JOIN OPTIONS o2 ON o2.id_car=c.id AND o2.option='ESP'
WHERE c.age >= 2  and works perfect

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this way and returns me both of ford 1 and 3....

I only want 3 Ford the with abs and esp

Answer (score 0):

Try it::

```
  Select new_car.name  
    From (select * from cars where year=2) as new_car 
    inner join option as op 
    on (op.id_car = new_car.id AND (op.option = `ABS` OR op.option = `ESP`))
```

:)