# Mysql select statement with 1-to-many tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to build up a mysql statement from an unknown array of variables (in php) that is passed to my class. The problem is not per se in building the statement (which I can do), but in creating a better, more efficient statement.

I've simplified the tables below to just show the core attributes.

Ive got one master table (a job)

### Job

```
jid, j_ref
```

Then this links to a second table that holds all the jobs properties

### Job_properties

```
jpid,jid,j_arg,j_value
```

Example data:

#### Job

```
jid: 1
j_ref: AB12345
```

#### Job_properties

```
jpid: 1, jid: 1, j_arg: address_1, j_value: 123 somewhere street
jpid: 2, jid: 1, j_arg: address_2, j_value: some lovely town
jpid: 3, jid: 1, j_arg: salary, j_value: 50000
jpid: 4, jid: 1, j_arg: job_type, j_value: permanent
....
```

So job 1 (jid=1), has those 4 properties (jpid is just a unique auto increment id).

Now when a search comes in I want to search based on the job_properties. The search can of course include some and/or any of the properties. I ONLY want to receive jid back from the query (obviously unique, so not 4 of the same jid).

The way I currently code this problem is to have multiple `IN` clauses which will produce something like:

`select j.jid from job j where

jid in (select jid from job_properties where j_arg='salary' and j_value > '40000')
and
jid in (select jid from job_properties where j_arg='address_2' and j_value='some lovely town') ... (insert more IN clauses for each value that is passed to the search)`

I loop through each variable in the array that is passed, and add another `IN` clause to the where statement.

I feel however that this is quite inefficient, and when I start receiving a large number of searches it will really slow down (a job can have 20-30 properties).

Is there a better way of doing this, maybe using HAVING and group by's?

It is similar to this question: [Select mysql data with where clause in 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805646/select-mysql-data-with-where-clause-in-2-tables), but I also need to query the argument in the other table, and not just the property.

Thanks in advance

Nick

P.S I can't cache results and not worry about the overhead on creation, as obviously results are dependant on the jobs in the database at the time of the search, and this changes hourly.

Comment: You can use joins instead of subquery. Usually joins are faster then subquerys

Comment: Yeah I know, but simple joins won't work in this instance. See (incorrect) answer below for why.

Answer (score 0):

Does this result in what you aim for?

```
SELECT 
  j.jid 
FROM 
  job j
  JOIN jop_properties jp ON j.jid = jp.jid
WHERE 
     ( j_arg = 'salary'    AND j_value > '40000'            )
  OR ( j_arg = 'address_2' AND j_value = 'some lovely town' )
  OR [insert more combinations here]
```

I guess this solution is too easy and I mistunderstood something.

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't. What this does it check the join record that the j_arg is equal to two different things, and j_value is equal to 2 different things.

Ie youd get job -> job property checked for that sql statement. Job property can't be two things at the same time, so it always fails. Dont know if thats explained well, but basically it doesn't work :?